# CSS Grid Layout - content collapsing on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, autoprefixer, css-grid

I'm trying to style a definition list with the new *CSS Grid Layout* using @support to get around older browsers. *Autoprefixer* changes it to a older version for *Edge*.

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-gap: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  -ms-grid-columns: min-content 1fr;
  
}

/* visual styles */
dl {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

dt {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Lorem</dt>
  <dd>Ipsum</dd>

  <dt>Lorem</dt>
  <dd>Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</dd>

  <dt>Longer Lorem</dt>
  <dd>Ipsum</dd>
</dl>
```

Looking at the code above, *Edge* collapses the whole content which is unreadable. Adding `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` pushes the `<dt>` and `<dd>` into the right columns.

All `<dt>`s should have the same width with the `min-content` of the largest one.

Is there a way to push the content into the correct rows without knowing the final amount of children of `<dl>`?

Comment: What @supports() rule are you using?

Comment: `@supports ((display:-ms-grid) or (display:grid))` I know I could just strip the support for Edge, but would like to know if there is some solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Edge supports an obsolete version of the CSS Grid Layout specification.

Edge is now implementing the current spec.

For more information about Edge support for Grid, including what works and what doesn't, and the status of implementation, see this page:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/grid/?q=grid%20update

Comment: Yeah, I noticed already that the older specification doesn't support `grid-auto-rows`. In that case I'll just add a fallback for Edge, thanks!